# C# Interaction in INDEX change all INDEX values JSON

Tags: c#, arrays, json

Im doing a INVENTORY System on C#. I have a array with size 6, that hold JSONDATA objects. But i have a problem, when i try to change ONE object field in one specific INDEX, all INDEX that contains a Object have the field changed too. Exemple:

```
Debug.Log ("SLOT 0 = "+inventory[0]["count"]);//Output 4
Debug.Log ("SLOT 1 = "+inventory[1]["count"]);//Output 4
inventory [0] ["count"] = 5; //Change INDEX 0 field "count" to 5
Debug.Log ("SLOT 0 = "+inventory[0]["count"]);//Output 5 --CHECK
Debug.Log ("SLOT 1 = "+inventory[1]["count"]);//Output 5 --WRONG
```

I don't know why that is happening, someone can help me?
Sorry my english, im from brazil.
Thanks.

--Edit
Hello @Steve, thanks for answer. I make a EDIT, because i can't comment u answer with all the code.
I use a for to run all INDEX of the array, if i have a EMPTY INDEX, i ADD a JSONDATA Object(ItemToAdd) to the INDEX.
The ItemToAdd is a JSONDATA object:
`{
"id": 1,
"name": "Item 1",
"type": "Tool",
"description": "1",
"count": 0,
"sellable": false,
"sellprice": 0,
"buyable": false,
"buyprice": 0,
"stackable": true,
"maxcount": 10,
"slug": "Item_1"
}`

The code that Run all array.

```
`for (int i = 0; i < container.Length; i++)
    {
        if (container [i] == null)
        {
            container [i] = ItemToAdd;//ADD ITEM TO ARRAY
            if (newItemCount > newItemMaxCount)
            {
                container [i] ["count"] = newItemMaxCount;
                newItemCount -= newItemMaxCount;
                newContainer = container;
            }
            else 
            {
                container [i] ["count"] = newItemCount;
                newItemCount = 0;
                left = newItemCount;
                itemSettings.NewItemCount = left;
                newContainer = container;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }`
```

If need to explain Variable, just talk.
Again, thanks for help and sorry my english.

Comment: And how are you changing the value? Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It seems that all your array elements are filled with the same reference. So modifying the element at any index change the same reference and you see the change everywhere. Please post the code where you fill the inventory array

Comment: I eddited the post, @Steve

Comment: As expected, you add always the same ItemToAdd to your elements. All your elements of the array references the same ItemToAdd , A change to ItemToAdd is seen in every index because every index points to the same ItemToAdd . You need to create a new ItemToAdd (whatever it is) at each loop if you want to have different references at each index.

Comment: I can just instanciate again the object? Some times, i will add the same ITEM to more than one INDEX... Thanks for answer, i will try here.

Comment: @Steve, the object ItemToAdd is recived as parameter by the function that add a item to my inventory, how can i create a new one ?

Comment: What kind of object is ItemToAdd? Can you call _TypeOfItemToAdd instance = new TypeOfItemToAdd();_ and then copy all the fields from the passed instance?

Comment: @Steve the type is JSONDATA. I did and still not working:
`JsonData newItem = new JsonData ();
newItem = ItemToAdd;
container [i] = newItem;`
Or i have to real all the object and copy to the newItem object?
Realy thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to write a simple method that deserialize your JSONDATA instance and rebuild a new JSONDATA instance

```
JSONDATA MakeCopy(JSONDATA source)
{
     string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source);
     return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONDATA>(result);
}
```

Now this object could be added to your array at the line

```
container[i] = MakeCopy(ItemToAdd);
```

Comment: Realy Thanks Steve! Do you have a link to a article that talk about Object References in Arrays? I realy don't knew about that. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, an array is nothing special. It is just a variable that stores a sequence of elements of value type or of reference type. All this problem boils down to understand what is exactly a reference vs a value.

Comment: There are two well known articles written by famous people here at SO that I suggest to read. The first is from Jon Skeet [Parameter passing in C#](http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) and the second is from Joseph Albahari author of LinqPad (if you don't know about it then I really suggest to download ASAP) and it is named [C# Concepts: Value vs Reference Types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx) Good read